# how to improve Max Potential First Input Delay when you have no javascript?

Tags: html, css

Chrome Lighthouse is telling me that to improve my performance I need to decrease my Max Potential First Input Delay (as it calls it). I searched how to improve it but I only found things related to javascript and my page is only using html and css (no javascript). Please can someone tell me how to improve it?
( I already minified my html and css )

Comment: Can you provide more details like stucture of your application and other details like how many pages you have and how many css you have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing source it's hard to pinpoint exactly, but from my experience the following can be used to improve *Potential First Input Delay* scores:

- Analytics scripts had a huge impact when loaded in the header.
- Deferring CSS loading can return huge rewards, but you need to weigh this up against any undesirable *Flashes of Unstyled Content*.
- Usage of rel="preload" to any external assets (images/fonts are prime culprits).

Good luck.